# Excel VBA - Match all instances of a value in range and return adjacent values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of people, each belonging to one or multiple groups. I need to find out all the groups that each individual belongs to.

In one column, I have the list of names. In another column, I have the **combined** list of names belonging to each group, with no spaces or separators between names. I want the result to show each name next to a cell containing all groups the person belongs to. See the example below, where the yellow columns are the desired result:

[image]

I thought about creating an array for each name, but I haven't had any success. Here is the vba I have so far, not sure if I'm headed in the right direction.

```
 Sub Test()
Dim range_1 As Range
Dim range_2 As Range

Set range_1 = Range("Names")
Set range_2 = Range("Combined_Names")

Dim v As Variant

Dim myArray() As Double, X As Long
X = 0
ReDim Preserve myArray(X)
For Each cell In range_1
    v = range_1.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            For Each cell In range_2
                w = range_2.Value
                If InStr(1, w, v, 1) Then
                    ReDim Preserve myArray(0 To X)
                    myArray(X) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    X = X + 1
                End If
        End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So the only way to distinguish your names is the capital letter? That is a really bad way to store data.

Comment: This is just a way to put it for simplicity, the real data has larger values.

Comment: I don't understand your reply. You should post your data as is.